# What is "HASH" in swift?

Tags: swift, hash

I am totally new to swift and  trying to call an API and it consists of some parameters which I have to pass. Due to security reason I cannot post the API. But one of the parameter(Comment) requires Hash value. I am getting this error :-

```
SUCCESS: {
    error = "Invalid parameter 'comment' value \"#\": Must be a Hash"
}
```

What I have understood that I have to pass some hash value as an parameter. For this I have used a function which will convert string into hashValue.

```
var hashValue : Int {
            get {
                return String(commentstr).hashValue
            }
        }
```

But still after doing this I am getting the same error. Am I in the direction? Anybody here can explain what am I missing?

Comment: This sounds like something specific with the API in question (and there's a good chance it could be completely unrelated from Swift's `hashValue`). You'd probably do better if you could share specifics of the API in question, or if you cannot do that, contact the provider of that API.

Comment: what type of hash API is expecting? is it MD5 or something different?

Comment: Without any information on that API, how can we know why it issues that error message? (Perhaps "Hash" refers to name of  the `#` character itself?)

Comment: This is nothing but your api requires to send # so better to talk with your server team , may be they can give you the exact reason for it

Comment: @Bluewings Let me try your solution.